# I'm trying to make load testing of my Telegram bot

Tags: jmeter, load, telegram

I'm trying to make load testing of my Telegram bot. So I tried to use HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder for that in JMeter and ran Proxy in Firefox for that, while did manipulations in my Telegram bot, but all that I had was just some random *.png files recorded in JMeter, which say me nothing and moreover, they came just ones and after records nothing, when I continue to work in the bot. When I record another sites request, everything is fine, but not Telegram. Read the following question and Rubycon says that there is only single Http Api request, but don't know which one and how to find that.
[Telegram Bot load testig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294658/telegram-bot-load-testig)
Can somebody help with that?

Comment: If you don't have a complex test scenario you don't need a recorder. Take a look at ddosify, it is very simple to use. https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) for recording Telegram network traffic you need to set Telegram to use JMeter as the proxy:

[image]

additionally you may need to install a [special loopback adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc708322(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) so Telegram wouldn't ignore local proxies and would be able to route traffic through them.

Also you will need to add JMeter's MITM certificate to [Trusted Root Certification Authorities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/trusted-root-certification-authorities-certificate-store)

[image]

More information: [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter)